# Wordpress meta key search

Tags: wordpress

I have some problems with wordpress meta key relations and search parametrs. I can not get this to work:

```
?meta_value=Dažādi&id=32&cp_city=Cēsis
```

Search results is only filtering by meta_value, not of cp_city and meta_value.

cp_city is also meta key value.

But this call is working and filtering:

```
?meta_value=Pārdod&id=32
```

I need to filter by two or three parametrs.

Here is functions code to filter.

```
<?php

if (empty($pilseta)) {
     $args=array(
    'post_type'          => 'ad_listing',
    'post_status'        => 'publish',
    'meta_key'           => 'cp_tips',
    'meta_value'         => $meta,
    'paged'              => $paged,
    'tax_query'          => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ad_cat',
            'terms' => $cat_id,      
            'field' => 'id'
        )
    )
);
}
else {
    $args=array(

    'post_type'          => 'ad_listing',
    'post_status'        => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'meta_key'           => 'cp_tips',
            'meta_value'         => $meta
        ),
         array(
            'meta_key'           => 'cp_city',
            'meta_value'         => $pilseta
        ),
    ),
    'paged'              => $paged,
    'tax_query'          => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ad_cat',
            'terms' => $cat_id,      
            'field' => 'id'
        )
    )
);
}



query_posts($args);
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Does you saw the SQL query generated by Wordpress to know if is ok?

After query_posts call, puts this:

```
<?php global $wpdb; echo $wpdb->last_query; ?>
```

If what WP is writing an unexpected query, I advice you to use [posts_where](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) filter with get_posts instead of query_posts

Answer (score 0):

Change the meta_key args file below and try:

```
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'cp_tips',
            'value'=> $meta
        ),
         array(
            'key'=> 'cp_city',
            'value'=> $pilseta
)
```